# SockJS not working on IE9 (Websockets)

Tags: websocket, internet-explorer-9, sockjs

I am trying to setup an app working with SockJS over STOMP. However, it seems that the connection is not established. I do not have these issues with running all on Chrome, FF and so on.

Is there a way to support this for IE9? Or is it impossible to run websockets with sockjs on IE9? I saw some discussions where people were solving some issues with IE9 and sockjs but none providing a solution to my issue.

BR

Comment: If you open the developer tools on IE, do you see any error? Sock.js should support IE9 by using alternative transports to websockets.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved. SockJS emulates websockets on IE9 with no issue. The only thing that I had to do was to provide absolute path for creating the SockJS object.

Before:

```
var webSocket = new SockJS('topic/publish');
```

After:

```
var webSocket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/topic/publish');
```

Although it was working with Chrome and Firefox, there were issues to run it on IE9 that doesn't support websockets (out of the box).

Comment: Do you have a question on stack? Create one and I will try to answer. But please provide all details with endpoints implementation, your js code etc.

Comment: As I tried, `SockJS 0.3.4` doesn't support IE9. `1.0.3` does.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 9 does not support websockets http://caniuse.com/websockets.

You can use a polyfill based on Flash like https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js

Comment: SockJS emulates websockets for IE9.

Comment: emulates or fallback to long polling?

Comment: Emulates by fallback.

Comment: web-socket-js emulates websocket with a TCP connection. Falling back to long polling is not emulating, it is using something else.

Comment: I am not talking about web-socket-js. Emulating is always doing one thing by using something else, moreover, in case of SockJS we get same results from the perspective of Spring and its websockets packages. In the end, I do not really care whether it is called as "using" or "emulating". For me what matters is that it works fine for IE9 and serves its purpose. I see no point in this nitpicking. For futher details please refer to the project site: https://github.com/sockjs.